# Por que usar métodos estáticos em python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando sobre o assunto do título e não consigo pegar a ideia com a explicação em vídeo e do Stk que encontrei, então quando e por que se utiliza método estático `@staticmethod` em python, tem-se algum ponto positivo além de simplesmente não referenciar o objeto com o `self` ( A pergunta se mantem para Closures / Decorators ( Que vejo sendo muito usado ( s ) em linguagens com Javascript mas em python ... ) em tal linguagem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Um método estático é um método que pode ser chamado sem a instancia da classe.

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def the_static_method(x):
        print x

MyClass.the_static_method(2)
```

É útil para se fazer operações dentro da classe, como uma função de calculo de área por exemplo. Você pode ter a classe Circulo e métodos que pode ser chamados sem precisar de instancia, pois o objetivo é o calculo:

```
class Pizza(object):
    def __init__(self, radius, height):
        self.radius = radius
        self.height = height

    @staticmethod
    def compute_area(radius):
         return math.pi * (radius ** 2)

    @classmethod
    def compute_volume(cls, height, radius):
         return height * cls.compute_area(radius)

    def get_volume(self):
        return self.compute_volume(self.height, self.radius)
```

Comment: Tem alguma referência para eu poder estudar mais sobre `@classmethod`?

Comment: https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Comment: Tu saberia me informar o nome que se da a esses ' itens ' ( Static met hod, property, class met hod ... ) da linguagem ?

Comment: A tradução seria Método estático, propriedade e método de classe. Mas se você está querendo saber o que são esses @ em cima dos métodos, isso é chamado de decorador.